# Capture Approver Comments-Issue solved

Tags: trigger, approval-process, after-trigger

**Sorry for all the trouble I am receiving the values right now with this same code unchanged.It was an issue in my passing values.
Here in the if conditions I have provided the conditions which are only updated after the approving part in the approval process.So only if it satisfies which means only if it is approved I get the values.
It is working.Issue was with my testing.**

Iam working on a trigger and right now I am able to pass an approval process and provide the next approver id through the trigger without the functionality in approval process) when the conditions are satified.I have to modify the trigger such that I can capture the comments written by the user when he approves /rejects it.
I tried using the processinstance id to **capture it in the second if condition** marked in stars.But I am only getting the submitter comments which I have provided in the trigger.

How do I capture the approver comments?

```
trigger Approval_Trigger on Grant_Contract__c (after update,after insert) {

User gUser = new User();
gUser=[SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id =:UserInfo.getUserId()];

List<Grant_Contract__c> lstAcc= new List<Grant_Contract__c>();
List<Id> Ids = New List <Id>();  

For(Grant_Contract__c c:trigger.New){
    Ids.add (c.Id);
               
    If( c.Stage__c =='Program Approved' && c.GrantContarctApprovalProcessInvoked__c == true && c.FinanceApprovalProcessinvoked__c == false) {
       
        system.debug('c.stage'+c.stage__c);
        Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1= new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
        req1.setComments('Request for approving from the finance team ');
        req1.setObjectId(c.id);
        req1.setProcessDefinitionNameOrId('Finance_Approval_Process');
        req1.setNextApproverIds(new Id[]{c.Request_Approval_From__c});
        Approval.ProcessResult res1 = Approval.process(req1);
        System.debug('offer submitted for approval successfully: '+res1);
    }
    **If( c.Stage__c =='Finance Approved' && c.GrantContarctApprovalProcessInvoked__c == true && c.FinanceApprovalProcessinvoked__c == true) {**
        **List<ProcessInstance> instances = [select Id, TargetObjectId from ProcessInstance where TargetObjectId in :Ids];**
        **Map<Id,Id> LeadProcessMap = new Map<Id,Id>();**
        **Ids = New List <Id>();**
        **for(ProcessInstance pi:instances){**
            **LeadProcessMap.put (pi.TargetObjectId,pi.Id);**
            **Ids.add (pi.Id);**
            **System.Debug ('** mapa1: '+LeadProcessMap);**
           **}**
            **List<ProcessInstanceStep> instancesSteps = [select Comments,ProcessInstanceId from ProcessInstanceStep where ProcessInstanceId in :Ids];**
            **Map<Id,String> LeadProcessStepMap = new Map<Id,String>();**
            **for(ProcessInstanceStep pis:instancesSteps){**
                **LeadProcessStepMap.put (pis.ProcessInstanceId, pis.Comments);**
                **System.Debug ('** mapa2: '+LeadProcessStepMap);**
               
                **c.Finance_Approval_Notes__c=pis.Comments**;
            **}
           
        }**
    
   
   
   
    // }
   
    update lstAcc;
    System.debug('lstAcc'+lstAcc);
}
```

}

Comment: Do you want to capture only approver comments?

Comment: @AnkaiahBandi Yes only those comments

Comment: @AnkaiahBandi Thanks for the time.I am getting the values